# Why am I unable to specify a sequence including the length of a bash array variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a script that looks through a series of directories for the presence of a file, and when found, pushes it onto the directory stack via `pushd`. The `dirs` command is insanely obnoxious, and I stumbled on the bash variable form of it's contents, `$DIRSTACK`

`$DIRSTACK` is an array of directories in the stack. It's always guaranteed to have 1 entry, the current working directory, and then pushed directories follow.

I'm attempting to iterate over the list of directories, but cannot seem to get the for-loop to accept the sequence length I'm attempting to automatically generate:

```
for i in {1..${#DIRSTACK[*]}}; do
  echo ${DIRSTACK[$i]}
done
```

When executed, bash fails with the following error:

```
line 72: {1..2}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1..2}")
```

I'm honestly stumped, because I've manually written `for i in {1..5}` in scripts a number of times without issue, and given the error message, it seems like the number of array items expansion is working exactly as I want it to.

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Nice to see Stack Overflow's syntax color has a bug.

Comment: The confusion about the error message is because the error is coming from the `echo` line rather than the `for` line. If you `echo "$i"`, you'll see that `{1..2}` is output. As dogbane said, the order of expansion is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar construct to a *sequence expression* is to use the `seq(1)` command.

For your specific case, you can use:

```
for i in $(seq ${#DIRSTACK[*]}); do
  echo ${DIRSTACK[$i]}
done
```

However, given your comment to @dogbane's answer, this will still not do what you want, since you are still iterating the number of elements in the array, but indexing past the end.

What you want is easily achieved by using bash's *substring expansion*, which also works on arrays.

```
for dir in "${DIRSTACK[@]:1}" ; do
  echo $dir
done
```

Comment: @DennisWilliamson That is actually what I wound up using. But will certainly be changing to the suggestions Gordon Davisson / camh have provided for substring expansion.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: How does `seq 5` differ from `seq 1 5`? According to the man page, they are the same so why put in the extra characters?

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, I was thinking `seq` did 0-based sequences. I use it so infrequently, I just got it wrong. Next time: `man` page first - then type comment (or not).

Answer (score 5):

Brace expansion will not work correctly if you have a parameter within it. This is because the parameter, `DIRSTACK`, in this case, won't be expanded until **AFTER** the brace has been expanded.

From the bash man page:

> Brace  expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any
>   characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. 
>   It is strictly textual.  Bash does not apply any syntactic
>   interpretation to the context of the expansion or the text between the
>   braces.

If you simply want to loop over the array, why not use the following?

```
for i in "${DIRSTACK[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```

Or, if you want to explicitly use the length of the array:

```
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#DIRSTACK[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    echo ${DIRSTACK[$i]}
done
```

Comment: I didn't realize bash supported long-form for loops. Unfortunately the reason why I don't want to loop over the array in that first form is because I have to skip the first item, because the current working directory is worthless to me. This is why I start the sequence at 1 instead of 0. I would love to just go over all the items but since I have to exclude one […]

Comment: @VxJasonxV: then use `for i in "${DIRSTACK[@]:1}"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson TOTALLY DOING THAT. Thanks :D!

Comment: As an aside, there are many shells with brace/sequence expansion. Only Bash performs them first. There are pros/cons to both - this is arguably one of the cons. They shouldn't be used for iteration anyway.

Comment: @ormaaj If I understand correctly, you're mentioning this for portabilities sake. Note that I do an explicit #!/bin/bash at the top of the file, and not merely #!/bin/sh. If I have not understood, please correct me.

Comment: @VxJasonxV Yes, that's the only reason. Brace expansion isn't POSIX, so it should never appear in a `/bin/sh` script to begin with. However if anyone ever runs across another shell that does have brace expansion, it will be different. It was originally a csh feature, but is quite widely adopted nevertheless.